# Check checkbox in table when click on table cell next to it

Tags: javascript, laravel, checkbox

I have a table with rows that look like this: ( 'o' is a checkbox)

```
_________________________________________
| o |  some label  | textarea  |    o    |
|___|______________|___________|_________|
```

this is it's code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered>
  @foreach ($labels as $label) 
    <tr>
      <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one /> 
      <td>{{ $label }}</td>
      <td class="with-textarea"><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox-two" /></td> 
    </tr>
  @foreach
</table>
```

How can I achieve that the left checkbox is checked when the user clicks either it or on 'some label' next to it?

I know I need javascript for it, but I don't have much knowledge.
Other similar questions were either really old or didn't help me further.

Comment: So why dont you handle the click event of that TD, and then use javascript to check the check box (I beleive you can access the check box from name) `<td onclick="YourJSFunction();">{{ $label }}</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case when you're clicking on the checkbox is done by default. For the label, you want to add a class to the `<td>`:

```
<td class="mylabel">{{ label }}</td>
```

And then use JS to bind an event handler:

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.mylabel');
labels.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const cb = e.parentNode.querySelector('.checkbox input');
    cb.checked = !cb.checked;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will mark this as answer as soon as SO let me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can done without JS like this:

```html
<table border="">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="id-1"></td>
   <td><label for="id-1">Click on me</label></td>
   <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="id-2"></td>
   <td><label for="id-2">Click on me</label></td>
   <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="id-3"></td>
   <td><label for="id-3">Click on me</label></td>
   <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```